# How to upgrade CKEditor (premium version)?

Tags: apex, visualforce

In Salesforce, RichText field uses CKEditor under the hood. 
It is possible to purchase license for full version of CKEditor.

I would like to know, how to upgrade CKEditor in Salesforce(after having purchased necessary licenses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is that you can not use all of the functionality there is a workaround to get access to the full editor. You can try something along the following lines (or you can even define the buttons you want but you would have to look into the CKEditor man pages):

```
<apex:page>
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/>
<script>
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e) {
        if (e.editor.config.magic) return;
        var target = e.editor.config.bodyId;
        var name = e.editor.name;
        e.editor.destroy();

        CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { config.magic = true; }
        CKEDITOR.replace(name, {
                    height : 600, 
                    bodyId : target
        });
    });
    // this next line is optional and removes the label to get the full width available for the editor
    $j('textarea').parent().prev().remove();
});
</script> 
.....
<apex:inputTextArea value="{!yourParamater}" richtext="true" />
.....
</apex:page>
```

Alternitavely you can set richText="false" on the textarea and use your own ckeditor from static resource yourself and use much of the script povided above.

Comment: +1 "set richText="false" on the textarea and use your own ckeditor from static resource yourself and use much of the script povided above."